# Refresh Bearer Token during Gatling Load Tests

Tags: testing, oauth-2.0, load, bearer-token, scala-gatling

How can I refresh my bearer (aouth2) token in gatling(written in scala) every 15 minutes during 3 hours tests?

I am able to get my token but I cannot apply it every 15 minutes in the scenario.

```
  def getXYZ() = {
    exec(
      http("Get all xyz")
        .get("/xyz/v1/abc")
    )
  }

  val authTimeout = 20.seconds
  val safetyMargin = 5.seconds
  val executionTime = 2.hours

  val tokenTimeout: ChainBuilder = exec(session => session.set("timeout", authTimeout.fromNow))
  val printSession: ChainBuilder = exec { session => println(session)
    session
  }

  def refreshAccessToken(): ChainBuilder = {
    exec(tokenTimeout)
    doIf(session => {
      session("timeout").as[Deadline].timeLeft <= safetyMargin
    }) {
      exec(
        http("Refresh Access Token")
          .post(url)
          .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
          .formParam("scope", scope)
          .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
          .header("Authorization", s"Basic $base64EncodedCredentials")
          .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").find.saveAs("accessToken"))
      )
        .exec(printSession)
    }
  }

  val scn = scenario("Scenario: Load Simulation With rampingUp Users")
    .exec(session => {
      val mytoken = session("accessToken")  // -->Trying the capture the token here
      println(mytoken.as[String])
      session
    })
    .exec(getXYZ())
    .pause(5)

setUp(
    scn.inject( ..... etc ...)
```

Comment: Did you get solution ? Even I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo code (in Java, supported since Gatling 3.7):

```java
// global mutable reference to a shared token
private volatile String token = null;

// first scenario refreshes the token
// must run with one single user 
ScenarioBuilder refresh = scenario("refresh")
.during(Duration.ofHours(3)).on(
  exec(http("refreshToken").get(???).check(saveToken))
  .exec(session ->
    {
      token = session.getString("token")
      return token;
    }
  ).pause(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
);


// second scenario uses the token,
// must start after the first one
ScenarioBuilder use = scenario("use")
  .exec(http("useToken").get(???).header("Bearer", session -> token))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer to my question. 
Unfortunately, I am still struggling with scala code. I am using asynchttpclient to get my token. But I cannot inject it in scenario because I am getting following error:

"scala gatling ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method exec in trait Execs of type"

Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: If you think you're struggling with Scala, hence you're not a Scala dev, why go with Scala? Gatling supports Java (or Kotlin).

Comment: I continue to one existing project, I overtook it. The problem here is not the scala itself but using a custom request feed on the fly of performance tests.

  def getXYZ() = {
    exec(
      http("Get all capabilities")
        .get("/xyz/v1/abc")
        .check(status.is(200))
    )
  }

  val scn = scenario("Scenario: Load Simulation With rampingUp Users")
    .exec(getXYZ())
    .exec(session => {
      val mytoken = session("accessToken")
      println(mytoken.as[String])
      session
    })
    .pause(5)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Stéphane LANDELLE,

I tried your pseudocode solution, and I'm finding some issues:

1. I see no way to use session inside the header method (it's just not there in IntelliJ autocompletion)
2. When I define scenarios like this, there is no way to ensure the token one executes before the other one

```java
    setUp(
      refreshToken.injectOpen(
        atOnceUsers(1)
      ).protocols(httpProtocolToken),
      doWhatever.injectOpen(
          rampUsers(handler.getUsers()).during(
              Duration.ofSeconds(handler.getRamp()))
      ).protocols(httpProtocol)
    )
```

3. When I define the Auth header as

```java
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
```

using your first scenario syntax to refresh the token (it works, if you put a breakpoint on the variable, it's updated, but), if it's initialized to null, it just stays like that, no matter what, in fact, if you put a breakpoint there, it won't stop. I think that implementation is that Scenarios are static unless you invoke session in the ActionBuilder (but I'm unable to do so as mentioned in point 1)

I think I reached a dead end unless I get some hints, thank you.