# Gatling: How to share dynamic authentication between virtual users?

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, performance-testing, gatling

Using Gatling (in Java), I would like to run a performance test against a backend needing some authentication via bearer token (JWT). The token expires after 5 minutes, so I'll need to renew it, if the test runs longer than that (which is the intention).

This is the way it's working for now:

```java
HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http.baseUrl("http://my.url/v1/")
    .authorizationHeader((session) -> session.getString("AuthToken"))
    .check(status().in(200, 401).saveAs("status"));

private String getAuthentication() {
  // retrieves and returns a new, valid authentication token via HttpURLConnection
  // this method has been proven to work correctly
}

ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("My scenario")
    .repeat(100).on(
        exec(http("My HTTP call").get("/my/endpoint"))
            .pause(1)
            .doIfOrElse((session -> session.getInt("status") == 401))
            .then(
                exec(session -> {
                    System.out.println("Got status 401 - retrieving new token");
                    return session.set("AuthToken", getAuthentication());
             }))
            .orElse(
                exec(session -> {
                    System.out.println("Got status: " + session.getInt("status"));
                    return session;
                })
            )
        );

    {
        setUp(
            scn.injectClosed(
                rampConcurrentUsers(5).to(40).during(1200), constantConcurrentUsers(40).during(600))
        ).protocols(httpProtocol);
    }
```

I'm OK with this solution, but I see the `getAuthentication` calls occurring too often, resulting in the authentication backend being called more often than necessary. I suppose this is due to the virtual users running in their own threads and the synchronization via the `session` variable does not happen (fast enough).

So, is there any smart way to have the authentification happen only one time, when needed, and share the token with all users?

Some things I thought of:

- Using the `synchronized` Java keyword on `getAuthentication` - did not change anything
- Creating a new Java Thread that will fetch a new authentication automatically every 4:30 minutes and write the new token to a variable which can then be accessed by the `authorizationHeader` call. Didn't try this yet as it seems a rather poor solution to me.

I have been searching around, as it seems, there are some more people facing the same challenge, but I haven't found any applicable solution there.

Bonus question: Is there any way to not count the 401 responses in the final statistics? :)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing some blocking operation (UrlConnection, synchronized) from Gatling's own threads is a very very bad idea. You're going to stall the whole engine.

Instead, you should update your shared token preemptively as you've described from a background task:

- either a dedicated Java thread if you want to stick to the blocking UrlConnection
- or a distinct Gatling scenario if you're willing to drop UrlConnection.

Note: this question has been asked several times on the [Gatling community forum](https://community.gatling.io/) and you'll find some examples there for the latter solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! After searching in the forum I think I found the way to go and will post it as an additional answer as soon as im content with it.

Answer (score 0):

With credit to Stéphane Landelle and the sources mentioned below, this is now my concrete implementation:

```java
public class MySimulation extends Simulation {

    protected volatile String token = "";

    protected HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
        .authorizationHeader((session) -> {
            return "Bearer " + token;
        })
        .check(status().in(200, 401));

    // Retrieving a new token
    ScenarioBuilder getToken = scenario("Acquire JWT")
        .exec(
            http("get token")
                .post(myAuthEndpoint)
                .body(myAuthBody)
                .check(
                    bodyString().find().transform(bodyString -> {
                        // extract auth token from response
                    })
                    .saveAs("AuthToken")
                )
            ).exitHereIfFailed()
        .exec(session -> {
            token = session.getString("AuthToken");
            return session;
        }).pause(Duration.ofSeconds(270)); // renew token every 4 minutes and 30 seconds

    // The actual load test
    ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("My scenario")
        .exec(http("My scenario")
            .get("/my/endpoint/with/parameters")
            .check(jsonPath(myJsonPath).ofString().is(whatIExpect)));

    // Start token retrieving alongside the actual load test
    {
        setUp(
            getToken.injectClosed(rampConcurrentUsers(1).to(1).during(1800)),
            scn.injectClosed(rampConcurrentUsers(5).to(40).during(1200),
                constantConcurrentUsers(40).during(600))
        ).protocols(httpProtocol);
    }
}
```

Possibly, there are more elegant solutions, but this should be a first sketch of how to implement it. The key is running the `getToken` scenario in parallel to the "real" test, having it pause just a little less than the token validity and renew the token accordingly. (Here the token validity period is 300s and the "Acquire JWT" scenario will run every 270s.)

The "Acquire token" needs to run as long as the real load test scenario. (Well - not really at all. Doing some arithmetics, one could omit the last, unnecessary run, shortening the duration of the overall test. But for my case, it is sufficient as it is.)

---

Helpful Sources:

[Refresh Bearer Token during Gatling Load Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886918/refresh-bearer-token-during-gatling-load-tests)

https://community.gatling.io/t/global-shared-token-is-populated-blank/8007/5

https://community.gatling.io/t/gatling-token-service-and-structure-of-simulation/1535/13

https://community.gatling.io/t/how-to-execute-the-first-request-only-once/6063/5